# Running jQuery function on single row rather than all?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code pasted below works fine and runs on select change, on multiple rows.

My problem is that I would rather it only would run on the row which the select change occurs

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $( document ).on( 'change', '#article-title select', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      jQuery("#orderrow_articles .acf-repeater .acf-row").each(function(i, element) {
       var row = $(element);
       var article_id = row.find("#article-title option:selected").val();
       var data = {
        articleid: article_id,
    };

  $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: rest_object.api_url + 'articleid/', 
      data: data,
      beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', rest_object.api_nonce );
      },
      success : function( response ) {
        var article_price = response.price;
        var article_description = response.description;
        row.find('#article-price-before-tax input').val(article_price);
        calculateQuote();
        row.find('#article-description textarea').val(article_description);
      },
      fail : function( response ) {
        console.log("error rest api 100");
      }
  });
});
});
});
```

What I want is when I select an option on row 3 for example, i only want article_price and article_description to be updated on row 3, rather than all of them.

Comment: You could try to bind the change event to the individual rows, or you could retrieve the clicked element from the ```e``` parameter in the document on change function: ```e.target``` https://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Comment: I think the issue happens because you are using `each` when you actually want the change to happen in one row only. It would be helpful to also post the html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by skipping each().

Solution:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $( document ).on( 'change', '.article-object', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var article_row_id_1 = e.target.id;
      var article_row_id_2 = article_row_id_1.substring(article_row_id_1.indexOf("row"));
      var article_row_id = article_row_id_2.substring(0, article_row_id_2.indexOf("-field"));
      var article_id = jQuery('tr[data-id*="'+article_row_id+'"] .article-object option:selected').val();
      console.log(article_row_id);
      console.log(article_id);
      var data = {
        articleid: article_id,
      };

      $.ajax({
          method: 'POST',
          url: rest_object.api_url + 'articleid/', 
          data: data,
          beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', rest_object.api_nonce );
          },
          success : function( response ) {
            var article_price = response.price;
            var article_description = response.description;
            jQuery(' tr[data-id*="'+article_row_id+'"] .article-price-before-tax input').val(article_price);
            calculateQuote();
            jQuery(' tr[data-id*="'+article_row_id+'"] .article-description textarea').val(article_description);
          },
          fail : function( response ) {
            console.log("error rest api 100");
          }
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i got from your problem, hopefully this will help you

First, you need unique identifier so you can select the match element, something like this

```
<div class="acf-row acf-row-{{your loop key / other identifier}}"></div>
```

Second, add data target so you can find the element

```
<select data-target=".acf-row-{{your loop key / other identifier}}"></select>
```

Third, code the js select target element with `data-attribute`, maybe you need to change `id` attr because 1 `id` only for 1 element in the page you should using `class`.

```
$('#article-title select').change(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $target = $(this).data('target')
    var data = {
        articleid: $(this).val()
    }

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: rest_object.api_url + 'articleid/',
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', rest_object.api_nonce);
        },
        success: function (response) {
            var article_price = response.price;
            var article_description = response.description;
            $target.find('#article-price-before-tax input').val(article_price);
            calculateQuote();
            $target.find('#article-description textarea').val(article_description);
        },
        fail: function (response) {
            console.log("error rest api 100");
        }
    });
})
```